# How to check which partition is a key assign to in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to debug a issue for which I am trying to prove that each distinct key only goes to 1 partition if the cluster is not rebalancing.

So I was wondering for a given topic, is there a way to determine which partition a key is send to?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[As explained here](http://www.agardner.me/kafka/big/data/partitioner/java/scala/byte/array/2016/01/23/kafka-partitioning.html) or [also in the source code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/DefaultPartitioner.java)

You need the `byte[] keyBytes` assuming it isn't null, then using `org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils`, you can run the following.

```
Utils.toPositive(Utils.murmur2(keyBytes)) % numPartitions;
```

For strings or JSON, it's UTF8 encoded, and the Utils class has helper functions to get that.
For Avro, such as Confluent serialized values, it's a bit more complicated (a magic byte, then a schema ID, then the data). See [Wire format](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/serializer-formatter.html#wire-format)

In Kafka Streams API, You should have a `ProcessorContext` available in your `Processor#init` , which you can store a reference to and then access in your `Processor#process` method, such as  `ctx.recordMetadata.get().partition()` (`recordMetadata` returns an `Optional`)

> only goes to 1 partition

This isn't a guarantee. Hashes can collide.

It makes more sense to say that a given key isn't in more than one partition.

> if the cluster is not rebalancing

Rebalancing will still preserve a partition value.

Comment: Why does DefaultPartitioner not use consistent hashing?

Comment: The calculation will return the same partition for the same key. Sounds consistent to me

Comment: I mean consistent hashing as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing. This remaps fewer keys compared to modular hashing, and it would be helpful if our consumers maintained state related to the keys.

Comment: The partitioner is overridable, I'm just answering the default case. I can't answer why one method was chosen over another

Answer (score 0):

when you send message,
Partitions are determined by the following classes

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/DefaultPartitioner.java

If you want change logics, implement org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Partitioner interface and, 
set ProduceConfig's 'partitioner.class'

reference docuement :
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs