# Can a single keyed message be read from a Kafka compact topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is it possible to read a single message from a Kafka compact topic if I know the message key?
I didn't find anything in the consumer Javadoc which looked like it would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kafka topics aren't indexed on keys, they are partitioned by them.

Yes, you can read a single message, regardless of compaction, but you can't read a topic starting from a particular key, only an offset.

Knowing a key, you can [find the partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50164566/) (assuming using default partitioner).

But that is the best you can do... You must scan the entire partition to then find that offset for a key

---

For example, using  [kafkacat](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat), print a key and the offset

```
kafkacat -C -b kafka:9092 -t topic-name -p 0 -f "key: %k; offset: %o\n" | grep key-value
```